# Color depth calculation

Tags: colors, depth

I want to know how to calculate the color depth of a picture with *these given items of data:*

1. the resolution of the picture.
2. the number of colors in the picture.

I actually need to calculate the needed storage in MB in order to display the pic and I'm missing the color depth in my calculations.

Thanks!

Comment: is it a grayscale or a color one with RGB channels or indexed mode?

Comment: and is resolution in dpi or like 100px x 100px? different people use different terminology...

Comment: I thought for a while... given these two things, afaik, we cannot calculate the color depth!

Comment: Hello. I've been told that there are 2^16 colors in the picture, it means that it's RGB, right? and the resolution is 1024px*768px.
Sorry for the late answer, I thought sof sends me an email telling me someone has answered..

Comment: Umm, really? I also had a struggle finding a way to find the color depth. What do you say about this: I have the number of colors so I'll just find 2^x which gives me this number.

Comment: you can do that 2^x method only if its grayscale or indexed image..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **`2^16` colors does not mean RGB**

   it means that pixel color information has `16bits -> 2^16 -> 65536` possibilities. It can be **RGB,YUV,Grayscale** or whatever else.
2. **picture size in Bytes**

   ```
   size = width[pixels] * height[pixels] * pixel size[BYTE]
   ```

   for 16 bit pixels it is 2 Bytes per pixels so:

   ```
   size = width*height*2 [Bytes]
   ```

   to get size in MB just divide it by `1024*1024` (or shift right by 20 bits)
3. **size of pixel in BYTES from number of colors**

   ```
   pixel size = ceil(log2(num of colors)/8)
   ```